# Full width title in Tufte document class with Fancyhdr

Tags: titles, tufte

I would like the title to span the full page rather than the 1st column. Tufte provides `fullwidth` for this however the title page overflows and shifts onto page 2.

*Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (14.0pt): 
 Make it at least 25.54448pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.*

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

%\geometry{showframe}% for debugging purposes -- displays the margins

\usepackage{amsmath}

% Set up the images/graphics package
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

\title{Investigating Alzheimer's Disease using Large Scale Models of Mammalian Thalamocortical Networks}
\author[Thomas H. Alderson]{Thomas H. Alderson}
\date{}  % if the \date{} command is left out, the current date will be used

% The following package makes prettier tables.  We're all about the bling!
\usepackage{booktabs}

% The units package provides nice, non-stacked fractions and better spacing
% for units.
\usepackage{units}

% The fancyvrb package lets us customize the formatting of verbatim
% environments.  We use a slightly smaller font.
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

% Small sections of multiple columns
\usepackage{multicol}

% Provides paragraphs of dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% These commands are used to pretty-print LaTeX commands
\newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}% optional command argument
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
\newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quote}\noindent}{\end{quote}}% command specification environment
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}% environment name
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% package name
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class option name

\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
\maketitle% this prints the handout title, author, and date
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document has just one column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure you really want this.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\geometry{showframe}% for debugging purposes -- displays the margins
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\title[Investigating Alzheimer's Disease]
      {Investigating Alzheimer's Disease using Large Scale Models
       of Mammalian Thalamocortical Networks}
\author[Thomas H. Alderson]{Thomas H. Alderson}
\date{}  % if the \date{} command is left out, the current date will be used

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
  \raggedright
  \maketitle
  \end{minipage}%
}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

The message about `\headheight is too small` is due to the long title in the heading, that I solved with a short title.